# How to use libevent to detect when file lock is released?

Tags: c++, linux, io, libevent, disk-io

While using libevent for detecting read/write readiness of non-blocking disk file descriptors (for files gaurded by mandatory locking), I faced the following issue:

When a file is locked for IO by another process, I get EAGAIN in current process when I issue read/write call, which perfectly aligns with the documented behavior of the APIs.

However, when these FDs are polled by libevent for IO readiness, they are detected to be IO ready which results in my callback to be called.

I have been trying to find a solution for this, but I dont know if I am searching on correct lines. Is it possible to avoid these calls?

Answer (score 0):

[According to POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/pselect.html):

> File descriptors associated with regular files shall always select true for ready to read, ready to write, and error conditions.

Not sure if there is a better way than spawning a thread that blocks on that file descriptor and then posts an event back to your I/O thread when the file is unlocked.

[inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) provides an event when a file is open or closed, but not when locked or unlocked, unfortunately.

Comment: I am trying to achieve asynchronous IO in a single threaded application. And since locks may not be only reason (theoretically) for EAGAIN, that approach will not work for me

Comment: @skaur Sometimes you have no other choice but to create another thread and let it block on something in order to avoid polling.

Comment: @maxim.. I dont have a choice then, i guess :)